# Attaching chained methods to collections of elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, collections, methods, element, chaining

This is—at least at the moment—purely experimentation, but I'm curious: is there a way to attach methods (via prototyping) to collections of elements? I've tested the following code:

```
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
<script>
NodeList.prototype._ = function(s)
 {
    for (x = 0; x < this.length; x++)
     {
        eval('this[x]' + '.' + s);
     }
    return this;
 }
document.getElementsByTagName('div')._("style.backgroundColor = 'red'")._('innerHTML += x');
</script>
```

At the moment, it works perfectly in Opera; just as would be expected, the _ method is being called on all of the div elements, and then eval()'ing the string passed to it *onto* each element in turn. Note that the _ method allows for chaining, and that's been demonstrated as well, calling _ to append the predicted **x** iterator variable to the innerHTML of each element.

Now, two questions...

First, is there a better way of going about this? I have for the longest wished I could just do `document.getElementsByTagName('div').style.backgroundColor = "red";`, but alas, it simply hasn't yet come to be. This is why I am doing this in the first place, and why I named the method so succinctly; I'm trying to emulate it as closely as possible.

Secondly, assuming this is a sane usage, how would I go about getting it to work in Firefox? That browser's equivalent of `NodeList` is `HTMLCollection`, but trying to prototype the latter simply doesn't succeed. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've cooked up what I suppose could stay as a viable solution; is there anything fundamentally bad about using this method to chain-modify a collection of elements?

```
<script>
_ = function()
 {
    for (x = 0; x < arguments[0].length; x++)
     {
        for (y = 0; y < arguments[1].length; y++)
         {
            eval('arguments[0][x]' + '.' + arguments[1][y]);
         }
     }
 }
</script>
```

Usage:

```
divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
_(divs, ["style.color = 'red'", "innerHTML += x"]);
```

Comment: Yes, you don't need eval for this.
Also since you actually have only 2 arguments, why not naming them and using arguments[]array?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'prettier' version (no eval, no globals, formal arguments, no fugly code inside strings) of what you need, not setting it on the prototype because that doesn't work for IE.

```
/**
 * Sets a property on each of the elements in the list
 * @param {NodeList} list
 * @param {string} prop The name of property to be set, 
 *        e.g., 'style.backgroundColor', 'value'.
 * @param {mixed} value what to set the value to
 */
function setListProp( list, prop, value) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        setProp(list[i], prop, value);
    }
}

/**
 * Avoids the use of eval to set properties that may contain dots
 * Why avoid eval? eval is slow and could be dangerous if input comes from 
 * an unsanitized source
 * @param {object} el object that will have its property set
 * @param {string} propName ('value', 'style.backgroundColor')
 * Example: setProp(node, 'style.backgroundColor', "#ddd");
 */
function setProp(el, propName, value) {
    var propList = propName.split('.');
    // Note we're not setting it to the last value in the property chain
    for (var i=0; i < propList.length - 1 ; i++) {
        el = el[propList[i]];
    }
    var lastProperty = propList[propList.length -1];
    el[lastProperty] = value;
}
```

***Test Case***
Go to google.com using Firefox, type the above code into the console, then type the following:

```
// Set tooltip on links
setListProp( document.getElementsByTagName('a'), 'title', 'YEAH it worked');


// Set bg to red on all links
setListProp( document.getElementsByTagName('a'), 'style.backgroundColor', '#f00');
```

**UPDATE**
My solution won't work if you want to be able to do += as you mentioned. The most elegant solution I think is to use a callback loop like the following.

```
/** 
 * This exists in many libs and in newer versions of JS on Array's prototype 
 * @param {Object[]} arr The array that we want to act on each element. 
 *                   Does not work for sparse arrays
 * @param {Function} callback The function to be called for each element, it will be passed
 *        the element as its first argument, the index as the secibd
 */
function iterate(arr, callback) {
  for (var i=0,item; item=arr[i]; i++) {
    callback(item, i);
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
iterate( as, function(el, index) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  el.innerHTML += "Whatever";
});
```